# Can't move objects with ipad

Tags: transforms, customization

The object moves when you drag it by pressing the g key and without clicking the mouse. But when I move an object with the ipad, I cannot move the mouse on the screen without clicking. Is it possible for me to move the mouse on the screen by holding left click instead of dragging it?
I'am using easycanvas.